# Can not display 3D obj file + texture using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to show a 3D model with texture on a website (using three.js to load .obj and .mtl file). But the model doesnt appear. I try to print out the obj and I got this [obj code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Uxj.png). Anyone knows what happened? There is no other error in the console anymore. The screen appear with the black ground color but no model. Appreciate if you could help. Thank you so much

```
        let container, stats;

        let camera, cameraTarget, scene, renderer;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 15 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );

            cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var OBJFile = '/program fixture.obj';
            var MTLFile = '/program fixture.mtl';
            const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
            manager.addHandler( /\.dds$/i, new DDSLoader() );
            
            new MTLLoader(manager).load(MTLFile, function ( materials ) {
                materials.preload();
                new OBJLoader ( manager ).setMaterials( materials ).load(OBJFile, function ( object ) {
                    console.log(object);
                    scene.add( object );
                });
            });
            

            camera.add( new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 ) );
            scene.add(camera);

            // renderer

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;

            renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
            
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
            controls.enableDamping = true
            controls.target.set(0, 1, 0)

            // stats

            stats = new Stats();
            container.appendChild( stats.dom );

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

        }


        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
            stats.update();

        }

        function render() {

            camera.lookAt( cameraTarget );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

Comment: The code section you have shared is insufficient for investigating the issue. Please share a complete live example.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code.

- You are using `OrbitControls` but then call `lookAt()` in the animation loop. Don't do that. Let `OrbitControls` focus the target.
- If you enable damping, you have to call `controls.update()` in the animation loop.
- Don't place the camera at the origin. The camera is probably "inside" the loaded asset and thus can't see it. Also increase the `far` value of the camera. Try it with:

```js
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );
```

- Also add some lights to your scene otherwise your loaded assets will appear black. Try it with:

```js
const hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444, 0.6 );
hemiLight.position.set( 0, 20, 0 );
.add( hemiLight );

const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
dirLight.position.set( 0, 100, 100 );
scene.add( dirLight );
```

Comment: I have removed lookAt(), add lights and change the camera position but it still not showing :(  still no error, just a black screen

Comment: Then please share a live example that demonstrates the issue.